# On a sectional, is there a way to determine if an airport is an Air Force/Naval base?

Tags: airport, aeronautical-charts

On the east coast, we have a lot of Air Force/Naval bases that are listed on sectionals.  Is there a quick way to determine that an airport is one of these?

[image]

Comment: I thought that "AFB/AAF/NS" was a dead giveaway :P

Comment: @aeroalias Agreed - this answer for the question you referenced was the one I was looking for.  Shame there isn't a quick way to spot these out.  Of course due diligence is key in flight planning, during flight discussions it would be nice to be able to spot them quickly.

Comment: The answer is found here http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7705/where-is-it-documented-an-airport-is-military As pointed out by aeroalias

Comment: yes, it is automatically shown on top of your post, there is no need of writing it again in the comments.

Comment: You are correct!  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Credit should be provided for the source of the map e.g. *Source: [SkyVector](https://skyvector.com/?ll=36.959329534594495,-76.18606566737331&chart=301&zoom=3)* to comply with the [license terms](https://skyvector.com/about).