# Can military personnel land their own private aircraft at military bases?

Tags: military, usa

First off, I am asking similar, but logistically different question to [What process do I follow to land a civilian aircraft on a military base?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/what-process-do-i-follow-to-land-a-civilian-aircraft-on-a-military-base)

If I am in the US Military (with a valid ID), am I free to land my personal (civilian style) airplane (with my civilian licence) at military bases - in the same sense that I could drive my car on?

Comment: I imagine the answer would be identical to [the other question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1072), except that instead of going directly to the base commander you'd submit your request through the chain of command, and special arrangements may be made so you don't have to notify the base commander 24 hours in advance of every intended landing...

Comment: Obviously that's an option.  But I wonder if you even need to do that as a member of the military, or if you can just show up.

Comment: 32 CFR 855, Table 1 (linked in [the answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/1077/64)) seems to indicate `Service members, operating their own aircraft, leased aircraft, or other available aircraft for official duty travel (temporary duty, permanent change of station, etc.) or for private, non revenue flights` are eligible for landing rights. It looks like they still need to file the paperwork, and with a few exceptions the request can be approved locally (at the base level).

Comment: You know, @voretaq7, if you want to put that into an answer.  It's definitely worthy.

Comment: I always tell passengers, when they ask if we can land at KNKX as we fly over it, that we can land anywhere you want to... once!

Comment: I seriously doubt you can drive your car onto any military installation you want without prior clearance. Same with an aircraft.

Comment: @jwenting - if you are military (what the question was about), you can certainly drive onto almost any military base with no prior clearance. The only exceptions would be the few high-security ones, like Groom Lake, etc.

Comment: ^^^what he/she said.

Comment: @jwenting they USED TO have stickers on cars that allowed people to drive right on and get waved (or saluted) on without any hassle.  Now you need to show an ID, but that's about it.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella interesting, thought they'd have tighter security in place, especially after things like the Ford Hood shooting...

Comment: @jwenting in THAT particular case, it wouldn't have helped since the shooter was a person that was assigned to that base.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As someone already said, [32 CFR 855, Table 1](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=80a5b18b20a48d67997e6d51e202012c&node=32:6.1.1.6.10&rgn=div5#32:6.1.1.6.10.3.1.5.9) states:

> Service members, operating their own aircraft, leased aircraft, or other available aircraft for official duty travel (temporary duty, permanent change of station, etc.) or for private, non revenue flights

This of course means you still need to contact base ops for a Prior Permission Required (PPR) of some sort (if required).  If the base has an [Aero club](https://www.usafservices.com/Managers/AeroClubs.aspx), then your logisitcal considerations are much less (most aircraft probably don't want to refuel on JP-8).  [The list of Aero Clubs seems to have decreased since I was in though](http://usmilitary.about.com/od/aeroclubs/).

The [Flight Infomration Handbook](http://navyflightmanuals.tpub.com/P-305/P-3050072.htm) will have all the base requirements listed in it.

Comment: Even military aircraft frequently need to get PPR's to land at other military fields.  It just ensures there is enough space and ground crew to handle the arriving aircraft.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, military personnel can apply for a Civil Aircraft Landing Permit for official business.